# denormalize adjusted to specific condition

Tags: r, denormalization

Could someone help me through this one i.e. I want to apply a function:

```
denormalize <- function(x,y) { 
return((x*(max(y) - min(y))) + min(y)) 
}
```

for the following data set, with each
Coefficient as "x":

[image: normalize model coefficient]

and data as "y":

[image: data]

The following returns the expected value, even though its not necessarily simple:

```
modelDenorm <- data.frame(cbind(Price = denormalize(modCoef$Price, data$Price),
                                Interest = denormalize(modCoef$Interest, data$Interest),
                                Inflation = denormalize(modCoef$Inflation, data$Inflation),
                                CCI = denormalize(modCoef$CCI, data$CCI)))
```

furthermore, are there any other applicable approaches? Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Use `mapply` to apply your function over both datasets. Just make sure to only pass the relevant columns in the correct order.

```
cols <- colnames(modCoef)
modelDenorm <- mapply(denormalize, modCoef[cols], data[cols])
```